# Issue with installing Opencv 3 for Python 3.5.1 on Mac OS X 10.11.4

Tags: python, installation, package, python-3.5

I have already installed `Opencv 3` using the Homebrew command:

```
brew install opencv3
```

in the Terminal. The issue is that this apparently installs it to the default system Python, which is version 2.7.10. I, however, need it for Python 3.5.1, which I can run using `python3` in Terminal and installed from the [official Python website](https://www.python.org). How would I install `Opencv 3` to this specific version of Python?

Comment: Not an answer but as a thought you could try modifying the startup script / configs for opencv to point to your python3 install

Comment: @Apcragg How would I do that?

Comment: I am note sure, which is why I didn't post it as an answer. I'd take a look on the wiki or in your install folder to find a config file or some sort of script that defines paths.  One other option is python virtualenv which allows applications all to use different python versions easily.